# How to get extract from a table using jsoup?

Tags: html-parsing, screen-scraping, jsoup

I have an element nested in a couple tables.

I want to know if this number is greater than `0`.

It is located here:

```
[@id="mainContent"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/
tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]
```

I used Chrome's copy xpath feature to get the path.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you could have used `Copy as HTML`

Comment: What have you got so far in java code?